# Period stops multiline regex substitute in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have multiple line string that I'd like to replace, but don't understand why it's not working. For some reason, a period in the string stops the matching for the regular expression.

My string:

```
s = """
[some_previous_text]
<start>
one_period .
<end>
[some_text_after]
"""
```

What I'd like to end up with:

```
s = """
[some_previous_text]
foo
[some_text_after]
"""
```

What I initially tried, but it doesn't match anything:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "<start>\none_period .\n<end>"
>>> print re.sub("<start>[^.]*<end>", "foo", s)
<start>
one_period .
<end>
```

However, when I took the period out, it worked fine:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "<start>\nno_period\n<end>"
>>> print re.sub("<start>[^.]*<end>", "foo", s)
foo
```

Also, when I put an `<end>` tag before the period, it matched the first `<end>` tag:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "<start>\n<end>\none_period .\n<end>"
>>> print re.sub("<start>[^.]*<end>", "foo", s)
foo
one_period .
<end>
```

So what's going on here? Why does the period stop the `[^.]*` matching?

EDIT:

**SOLVED**

I mistakenly thought that the carat `^` was for new-line matching. What I needed was a re.DOTALL flag (as indicated by Amber). Here's the expression I'm now using:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "<start>\none_period .\n<end>"
>>> print re.sub("<start>.*<end>", "foo", s, flags=re.DOTALL)
foo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why wouldn't it? `[^.]` is "the set of all characters that is not a `.`" and thus doesn't match periods.

---

Perhaps you instead meant to just put `.*` (any number of any characters) instead of `[^.]*`?

For matching across newlines, specify `re.DOTALL`:

```
re.sub("<start>.*<end>", "foo", s, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: if I use `.*`, though, it doesn't match anything (i.e. `re.sub("<start>.*<end>", "foo", s)`). What would be a correct substitution expression?

Comment: If you want `.` to match across lines, you need to use the `re.DOTALL` flag. http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL

Comment: `re.sub("<start>.*<end>", "foo", s, flags=re.DOTALL)` works! Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because `[^.]*` is a negated character class that matches any character but a period.

You probably want something like `<start>.*?<end>` together with the `re.S` modifier, that makes the dot matches also newline characters.

```
re.sub("<start>.*?<end>", "foo", s, flags=re.S)
```

Comment: @user749618 I updated my answer. `re.S` is the same than `re.DOTALL` that Amber suggested.

Comment: Note that `re.sub()` only accepts the flags argument in Python 2.7 or Python 3.1+, before that you will either need to compile the regex with the flag set or use something like `[\s\S]*?` instead of `.*?`.